# Do views immediately reflect data changes in their underlying tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, view

I have a view `ObjectDisplay` that is composed of two relevant tables:  `Object` and `State`.  `State` represents the state of an `Object`, and the view pulls some of the details from the most recent `State` for each `Object`.

On the page that is displaying this information, a user can enter some comments, which creates a new `State`.  After creating the new `State`, I immediately pull the `Object` from `ObjectDisplay` and send it back to be dropped into a partial view and replace the `Object` in the grid on the page.

```
// Add new State.
db.States.Add(new State()
{
    ObjectId = objectId,
    Comments = comments,
    UserName = username
});

// Save the changes (executes all of the above).
db.SaveChanges();

// Return the new Object information.
return db.Objects.Single(c => c.ObjectId == objectId);
```

According to my db trace, the `Single` call occurs about 70 ms after the `SaveChanges` call, and it occurs on the same SPID.

Now for the issue:  <s>The database defaults the value of `RecordDate` in `State` to `GETUTCDATE()` - I don't provide the date myself.  What I'm seeing is that the `Object` returned has the `State`'s `RecordDate` of the old `State` and the `Comments` of the new `State` information of the old `State`.</s>  I am seeing that the `Object` returned has the old `State`'s information.  When I refresh the page, all the correct information is there, but the wrong information is returned in the initial call from the database/EF.

So.. what could be wrong?  Could the view not be updating quickly enough?  Could something be going on with EF?  I don't really know where to start looking.

Comment: What isolation levels are the queries running with? Is the view being called on a different session to the query that changes data?

Comment: @Oded:  From the trace, the `Audit Login` line has `set transaction isolation level read committed`.  Both are being done in the same SPID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've previously loaded the same `Object` entity in the same `DbContext`, EF will return the cached instance with the stale values, and ignore the values returned from SQL.

The simplest solution is to reload the entity before returning it:

```
var result = db.Objects.Single(c => c.ObjectId == objectId);
db.Entry(result).Reload();
return result;
```

Comment: That was my first thought too, but the OP sees the query being executed in profiler. If the cached value would be used, the query should not get executed at all.

Comment: The `Reload` works, and I do load the `Object` earlier in the same `DbContext`.  I wonder why it goes to the database and then ignores the results and uses the cached values - because that is indeed exactly what is happening (even if I switch to `First` instead of `Single`).  Looks like the best thing to do here is to `Reload` the original `Object` that I pull earlier in the `DbContext`.  Thanks for this!

Comment: @SebastianMeine: Unfortunately, the query will still get executed, but EF will throw the results away.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed odd. In SQL Server views are not persisted by default and therefore show changes in the underlying data right away. You can create a clustered index on a view with effectively persists the query, but in that case the data is updated synchronously, so you should see the change right away.

If you are working with snapshot isolation level your changes might not be visible to other SPIDs right away, but as you are on the same SPID and do not use snapshot isolation, this cant be the culprit either.

The only thing left at this point is the application layer. Are you actually using the result of the Single call higher up in the call stack or does that get lost somewhere. I assume that a refresh of the page uses a different code path, which would explain why it is working there.

Comment: I am using the result to update that row within my data grid in the web application making the call.  The refresh does indeed use a different code path (loads the entire grid through a different service operation).